# Method x has no supported translation to SQL

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I want to write a query which should get an user object and the amount of messages the user has posted already. I did this the following way:

```
var query = (from u in _db.Repository<User>()
             where u.IsDeleted != true
             select new UserWithMessagecount()
             {
                 User = u
                 MessageCount = GetUserMessageCount(u.Documents).Count(),
             });
```

**I'm using a method because some messages should be filtered out (in a dynamic way)**.

To keep things simple I'll post the function without sorting logic (which still produces the same error).

```
    private EntitySet<Document> GetUserMessageCount(EntitySet<Document> set)
    {
        return set;
    }
```

The error returned is:

Method 'x' has no supported translation to SQL.

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Comment: I've been trying to reproduce this issue to look for an alternative solution using sql clr integration feature. I'm unable to reproduce this error. Can you help me a bit. Here is my code: `DataContext dataContext = new DataContext("conn string");
            Table<Customer> customers = dataContext.GetTable<Customer>();

            var q1 = from c in customers
                     select new { SuffixName = AddNewSuffix(c.Name) };`  My linq query is able to pick the locally defined function AddNewSuffix in my C# code instead of giving sql server side translation error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use this syntax instead:

```
 var query = (from u in _db.Repository<User>()
             let MessageCount = GetUserMessageCount(u.Documents).Count()
             where u.IsDeleted != true
             select new UserWithMessagecount()
             {
                 User = u,
                 MessageCount = MessageCount
             });
```

Comment: Is it possible to get rid of this error by adding this function `GetUserMessageCount` in SQL server itself using sql server clr integration feature?

Comment: sure you can, check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865310/how-to-create-a-method-that-suport-translation-to-sql

Comment: Can you please have a look at the problem I'm facing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37814449/linq-to-sql-unable-to-use-sql-server-udfs-in-linq-query. I've tried the steps suggested in the link but I'm not getting the dataContext override stuff.

Answer (score 7):

Linq-to-SQL will be trying to convert your *entire* statment into SQL, an of course there is no GetUserMessageCount() available.

You will need to take the results of the SQL query by enumerating it -- then apply the C# side logic.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to use grouping in your projection.

```
var query = from u in _db.Repository<User>()
            where !u.IsDeleted
            group u by u.UserId into g
            select new UserWithMessageCount {
               User = g.First(x => x.UserId == g.Key),
               MessageCount = g.Sum(x => x.Messages.Count())
            }
```

This should work.