# [System.DateTime])' has no supported translation to SQL

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I want to execute a query like this:

```
List<supervisorAnswerQuesttionPres> temp =
    (from i in dbconnect.tblAnswerLists
    where i.StudentNum == studentNumber
    select new supervisorAnswerQuesttionPres
    {
        answerList = _resAnswerList,
        questionList = _resQuestionist,
        date = ConvertToPersianToShow(i.dateOfAnswer.Value.Date)
    }).OrderBy(i => i.date).ToList();
```

My class that this query is returned is something like this :

```
public class supervisorAnswerQuesttionPres
{
    public string date { set; get; }
    public List<string> questionList { set; get; }
    public List<string> answerList { set; get; }
}
```

In this query i use a function to convert my Datetime to another presentation i use this function for this :

```
public string ConvertToPersianToShow(DateTime? datetime)
{
    string date;
    DateTime dt;

    if (!datetime.HasValue) return "";
    dt = datetime.Value;
    //  dt = datetime;

    string year = Convert.ToString(persian_date.GetYear(dt));
    string month = Convert.ToString(persian_date.GetMonth(dt));
    string day = Convert.ToString(persian_date.GetDayOfMonth(dt));

    if (month.Length == 1)
    {
        month = "0" + Convert.ToString(persian_date.GetMonth(dt));
    }

    if (day.Length == 1)
    {
        day = "0" + Convert.ToString(persian_date.GetDayOfMonth(dt));
    }

    Convert.ToString(persian_date.GetMonth(dt)) + "/" +
            +                 dt.Minute + ")";
    date = year + "/" + month + "/" + day;
    return date;
}
```

This function just convert my DateTime ,But when i execute the query i got this error:

```
Method 'System.String ConvertToPersianToShow(System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime])' has no supported translation to SQL.
```

Comment: You shouldn't be doing View logic in your Data Access Layer.

Comment: Yes you are right .And i will change it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's trying to convert the query into SQL, but doesn't know how to convert the `ConvertToPersianToShow` method.

The solution is to call `ToList()` after the where clause to bring the entities into memory, then do the select:

```
var temp = dbconnect.tblAnswerLists
    .Where(i => i.StudentNum == studentNumber)
    .ToList() // <-- This will bring the data into memory.
    .Select(i => new supervisorAnswerQuesttionPres
        {
            answerList = _resAnswerList,
            questionList = _resQuestionist,
            date = ConvertToPersianToShow(i.dateOfAnswer.Value.Date)
        })
    .OrderBy(i => i.date)
    .ToList()
```

When calling `ToList()`, the query is translated into SQL, e.g. something like

```
SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE StudentNum = '<studentNumber>'
```

and executed against the database. When the data returns and you have it in memory, you can use [LINQ to Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397919.aspx) to query and manipulate the data further.

**NOTE!** Generally you should be careful to call `ToList` before you've added *at least* a where clause, otherwise you'll end up fetching **way too much** data into memory.

Comment: Apologies for using the extension method synax, I just find it so much sexier ;)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 var temp = (from i in dbconnect.tblAnswerLists
                    let pDate = ConvertToPersianToShow(i.dateOfAnswer.Value.Date)
                    where i.StudentNum == studentNumber

                    select new PresentClass.supervisorAnswerQuesttionPres
                    {
                        answerList = _resAnswerList,
                        questionList = _resQuestionist,
                        date = pDate
                    }).OrderBy(i => i.date).ToList();
```

reference: [Method x has no supported translation to SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309338/method-x-has-no-supported-translation-to-sql)

Comment: Not a good idea at all. I doubt it would work. If it does work, it would be via Linq To Object.

Comment: Hmm, if you still get that error I would look at what khellang did.  Fetch into memory first, then project to supervisorAnswerQuesttionPres.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ to SQL does not know how to translate a call your method 'ConvertToPersianToShow' into SQL in order to execute the where clause on the server.  Your method does not exist on the server.

maybe something like this would help, but if it doesn't work you should fetch your data and then change it to the way you want it to be shown as

```
List<PresentClass.supervisorAnswerQuesttionPres> temp 
= (from i in dbconnect.tblAnswerLists
   let PDate=ConvertToPersianToShow(i.dateOfAnswer.Value.Date)
   where i.StudentNum == studentNumber
   select new PresentClass.supervisorAnswerQuesttionPres
   {
    answerList = _resAnswerList,
    questionList = _resQuestionist,
    date = PDate
   }).OrderBy(i=>i.date).ToList();
```

Comment: I called this method before in another project and it worked ,i don't know why doesn't work here

Comment: In the other project you used the same exact query?

Comment: No ,I mean use **ConvertToPersianToShow** between the query syntax and it worked ,

Answer (score 1):

As some people have noted, you can't run C# in SQL (well...lets ignore SQL CLR).

However your real problem comes from your poorly architected program.

Your data layer is doing display logic, and none of the Microsoft engineers expected that.

You should bring your data out of the database first. Then on your display logic use `ConvertToPersianToShow(DateTime?)` to bind to your view.

```
public class SupervisorAnswerQuestion
{
    public DateTime? Date { set; get; }
    public List<string> Questions { set; get; }
    public List<string> Answers { set; get; }
}

public class SupervisorAnswerQuestionViewModel
{
    public SupervisorAnswerQuestion SupervisorAnswerQuestion {get;set;}
    public string DateFormated 
    {
        get { return SupervisorAnswerQuestion.Date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
    }
}
```

Actual come to think of it. Scrap `ConvertToPersianToShow`, learn `DateTime.ToString(string)` for datetime formatting.